# Can UK CAA modular exams done before Brexit be used towards an EASA license?

Tags: pilot-certification, easa, uk

I am stuck with some EASA basic modules (Form 148) and some UK CAA modular exams.

Now I want to apply to get an EASA B1.1 license but the problem is German aviation authority (Luftfahrtbundesamt) is not accepting the modules by UK CAA even though the exams were held before the Brexit.

Can anybody recommend me something from where should I apply for EASA B1.1 license? Or do I have to re-appear in the modules given by UK CAA?